# Stretch a div to the edge of screen

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a menu that stretches to the right edge of browser, with any screen width. Here's what I want to do:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3GSe.jpg

I'm using `position: absolute;` and `width: 100%;` to make `#greenbar` to stretch outside the `#menu` div. But it covers all the menu in width, not only on the right side.

**HTML:**

```
<header id="nav">
        <h1><a href="#">Title</a></h1>
        <div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li class="menu_button"><a>button1</a></li>
                <li class="menu_button"><a>button2</a></li>
                <li class="menu_button"><a>button3</a></li>
                <li class="menu_button"><a>button4</a></li>
                <li id="greenbar"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>        
</header>
```

**CSS:**

```
#menu{
    float: right;
    margin-top: 35px;
}

.menu_button{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 16px 25px;
    background-color: #39b54a;
    color: #fff;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}

.menu_button:hover{
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #39b54a;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 300ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background-color 300ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: background-color 300ms ease-in-out;
    transition: background-color 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.menu_button a:hover{
}

.menu_button a{
    float: left;
    font-family: "Gotham";
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#greenbar{
    float: right;
    padding: 24px;
    background-color: #39b54a;
}
```

Comment: if you post a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ you'll get better answers.

Comment: it also looks like you might need to change your display to in-line block but I cant tell without a more code.

Comment: Anonymous.X : it's greenbar, not greenride, sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood of what you want, you can use `padding-left` so the div won't reach the edge of the left side of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're using position absolute? Here's what'd I'd do minus the transitions.

```
#nav {background:#39b54a;}
#nav:after,#menu> ul:after{content:''; display:block; visability:hidden;clear:both;}/*doesn't work in ie5 or 6*/
/*use clear:both; on the last element*/
#menu {float:right;}
#menu> ul> li {float:left;}
```

Where ever you have floats. Don't forget to clear them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to add a background color to your navbar that spans the whole page. If that's the case, update the `#menu` like so:

```
#menu{
    float: right;
    margin-top: 35px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #39b54a;
}
```

**Updated:** You can wrap your `menu` div in a `menu-wrapper` and create a left margin offset:

```
<header id="nav">
        <h1><a href="#">Title</a></h1>
        <div id="menu-wrapper">
            <div id="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li class="menu_button"><a>button1</a></li>
                    <li class="menu_button"><a>button2</a></li>
                    <li class="menu_button"><a>button3</a></li>
                    <li class="menu_button"><a>button4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>     
        </div>
</header>
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/gkwpwwyg/1/

Comment: Tried it, it stretches the navbar on the whole width, but my menu must be positioned on the right side of the navbar.

Comment: Updated my answer, should get you closer to where you want to be.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this could help you or not, but I think so.

Using table as the wrapper, so you can position it.

HTML:

```
<header id="nav">
 <table id="menu_table">
  <tr>
   <td class="menu_button">
    <a href="#" class="menu_a">button 1</a>
   </td>
   <td class="menu_button">
    <a href="#" class="menu_a">button 2</a>
   </td>
   <td class="menu_button">
    <a href="#" class="menu_a">button 3</a>
   </td>
   <td class="menu_button">
    <a href="#" class="menu_a">button 4</a>
   </td>
   <td id="greenbar">
    &nbsp;
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
#menu_table {
    width: 80%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 20%; //make the table away from edge 20% of SCREEN
}

.menu_button{
    padding: 16px 25px;
    background-color: #39b54a;
    color: #fff;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #fff;
    border-width: 0px 1px 0px 0px; /*this will add space between button*/
    width: 20%; //width is 20% of table's width
    }

.menu_button:hover{
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #39b54a;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 300ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background-color 300ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: background-color 300ms ease-in-out;
    transition: background-color 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.menu_a {
    font-family: "Gotham";
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#greenbar{
    width: 20%;
    padding: 24px;
    background-color: #39b54a;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

I'm new to coding. Please apologise if something went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

All right, I added this to my #menu div :

```
position: absolute;
right: 0;
width: 50%;
```

The menu now sticks to the right edge of the screen, then I removed `float: right` from the #greenbar div.

My menu now takes 50% of the screen, and the greenbar stretches to the edge.